# what is the Error in int object iteration?

Tags: python, object, int

What is 'int' object is not subscriptable in this code?

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the hourglassSum function below.
def hourglassSum(arr):
    sum1=0
    result=0
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            sum1=arr[i][j]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j+2]+arr[i+2[j+2]]
        if sum1>result:
            result=sum1
    return result



if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    arr = []

    for _ in range(6):
        arr.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = hourglassSum(arr)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do: `arr[i+2[j+2]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

The very last part of this long line:

```
sum1=arr[i][j]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j+2]+arr[i+2[j+2]]
```

(this part here):

```
arr[i+2[j+2]]
```

Is an error; you seem to be trying to refer to `2[j+2]`.  Clearly the integer `2` is not an array, so Python complains to you that it makes no sense to index an integer.

You probably want that last term to be:

```
arr[i+2][j+2]
```

Looking more closely at the long line, it seems like what you are trying to accomplish is obtain the sum of the elements in a 3x3 section of `arr`. But even the long line is missing some of the combinations. Rather than risk typing the list of addition problems incorrectly (because there are so many), use a set of nested loops to build up the sum of the 3x3 segment.